# Azure Functions for python, structured logging to Application Insights?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights

When using Python (3.8) in Azure Functions, is there a way to send structured logs to Application Insights? More specifically, I'm trying to send custom dimensions with a log message. All I could find about logging is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#logging) very brief section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update 0127:**

It's solved as per [this github issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/788#issuecomment-765638259). And here is the sample code:

```
# Change Instrumentation Key and Ingestion Endpoint before you run this function app

import logging

import azure.functions as func
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

logger_opencensus = logging.getLogger('opencensus')
logger_opencensus.addHandler(
    AzureLogHandler(
        connection_string='InstrumentationKey=aaaaaaaa-bbbb-cccc-dddd-eeeeeeeeeeee;IngestionEndpoint=https://eastus-6.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/'
    )
)

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    properties = {
        'custom_dimensions': {
            'key_1': 'value_1',
            'key_2': 'value_2'
        }
    }

    logger_opencensus.info('logger_opencensus.info Custom Dimension', extra=properties)
    logger_opencensus.info('logger_opencensus.info Statement')
    return func.HttpResponse("OK")
```

---

Please try [OpenCensus Python SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#instrument-with-opencensus-python-sdk-for-azure-monitor).

The example code is in the [Logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opencensus-python#logs) section, step 5:

**Description:** You can also add custom properties to your log messages in the extra keyword argument by using the `custom_dimensions` field. These properties appear as key-value pairs in customDimensions in Azure Monitor.

**The sample**:

```
import logging

from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
# TODO: replace the all-zero GUID with your instrumentation key.
logger.addHandler(AzureLogHandler(
    connection_string='InstrumentationKey=00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')
)

properties = {'custom_dimensions': {'key_1': 'value_1', 'key_2': 'value_2'}}

# Use properties in logging statements
logger.warning('action', extra=properties)
```

Comment: thanks, I know that part (and am using it in another, non-Function app. But ideally I don't want to add another logger, since there is already the logger available in the Function. I'm afraid doing so, I would probably lose any correlation

Comment: this Github discussion actually produced a working example which is not too far away from yours. If you want to amend your answer, I'll mark it as accepted https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/788#issuecomment-765638259

Comment: @silent, included it in the answer. If it's helpful, please accept it as answer:).

Comment: @ivan-young sorry, I was happy a bit too early... it turns out the correlation doesnt work properly with that code snippet. I'm currently in contact with support/PG to sort that out

Comment: @silent thanks for pointing this out. Let's wait for the response from support team:).

Comment: I try your sample code, but I find that it causes duplicate logging messages on applicationInsights. How can I fix it?

Comment: "OpenCensus Python SDK is deprecated, but Microsoft supports it until retirement on September 30, 2024. We now recommend the OpenTelemetry-based Python offering and provide migration guidance."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-python-opencensus-migrate?tabs=python

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking about, but in my case I wanted to be able to always send a custom_dimension value depending on some initialization configuration, without having to use the `extra` parameter on each log request. For example to know from what cron job the telemetry was coming from.

I solved it with a filter:

```py
import logging
from opencensus.ext.azure.log_exporter import AzureLogHandler


logger = logging.getLogger()
handler = AzureLogHandler(connection_string='InstrumentationKey=...')
logger.addHandler(handler)

def add_custom_dimension(e):
    e.custom_dimensions = {'job_name': '123'}
    return True

logger.addFilter(add_custom_dimension)

logger.error("test")
```